# Repeat a div when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, repeat

The below code is for repeating a div. But it does not work. Please help me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(".repeat").live('click', function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.after($self.parent().clone());
        $self.remove();
      });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="repeatable">
        <table border="1">
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="userInput[]"></td></tr></table>
        <button class="repeat">Add Another</button>
      </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you miss jquery including

Comment: @ Ushakov Nik... i included but it does not work

Comment: I dont know if it was your intent but you code is repeating a div inside it's cloned source: a div `.repeatable` inside another `.repeatable`. If you want them to be the same hierarchy level try: `var parent = $self.parent(); parent.after(parent.clone());`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add `jquery` in your `code` and use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) in place of [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live).

Also write your code in `$(function(){...})` so, that your code will work after `document ready`

```
<script src="http:/code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function () {
       $(".repeat").on('click', function () {
          var $self = $(this);
          $self.after($self.parent().clone());
          $self.remove();
       });
   });
</script>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yjtju/)

**Updated,** if you want it to work for `more inputs` then try this,

```
$(function () {
    $(".repeat").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();// to prevent form submit
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.before($self.prev('table').clone());// use prev() not parent()
        //$self.remove();// remove this line so you can add more inputs
    });
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yjtju/1/)

Comment: it only repeate two times after that it second div disappears.... i need repeat that div each time when i click a button

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).on('click', '.repeat', function () {
```

instead of

```
$(".repeat").live('click', function () {
```

Comment: By the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/): As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: So, if you agree you can update your answer to increase it's quality.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(".repeat")` construction says that jQuery must be used.
Try to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` before your `<script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="parent">
      <div class="repeatable">
        <table border="1">
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="userInput[]"></td></tr></table>
        <button class="repeat">Add Another</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.repeat', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.repeatable').parent('div.parent').append($('.parent').children('div:first').html());
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robincharummoottil/L37Le/),